# remove absolute dependency path from `.classpath`; relative path doesn't work

Tags: java, classpath

I am not a Java programmer.
I did some Java programming in the past but nothing big.

There is one tool which I use, written in Java which I want to improve.

I got the sources of the tool.
I want to make a small change
(in how it parses input files, to add support for a different file format)
then compile the tool
upload updates to repository
end of story.

But first I have to be able to compile the original project.
I opened the project in Visual Studio Code.
I got errors

```
Project 'UVW' is missing required library: 'D:\xyz-workspace\java\_libraries\jfreechart-1.0.19\lib\jcommon-1.0.23.jar'
Project 'UVW' is missing required library: 'D:\xyz-workspace\java\_libraries\jfreechart-1.0.19\lib\jfreechart-1.0.19.jar'
Project 'UVW' is missing required library: 'D:\xyz-workspace\java\_libraries\gson-2.2.2.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

Great,
the guy who did the tool added dependency to libraries on his own computer.
(here I replaced the project name with `UVW` and the author's name with `xyz` for privacy).

I check `.classpath`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar" sourcepath="D:/xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/source">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="D:/xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/source"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/gson-2.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

So in the project directory I simply create the `xyz-workspace`, I replicate the structure and put there the missing libraries.
Then I edit the paths to be relative:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="./xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="./xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar" sourcepath="./xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/source">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="D:/xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/source"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="./xyz-workspace/java/_libraries/gson-2.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Ok,
but this still fails:

```
Project 'UVW' is missing required library: 'xyz-workspace\java\_libraries\jfreechart-1.0.19\lib\jcommon-1.0.23.jar'
Project 'UVW' is missing required library: 'xyz-workspace\java\_libraries\jfreechart-1.0.19\lib\jfreechart-1.0.19.jar'
Project 'UVW' is missing required library: 'xyz-workspace\java\_libraries\gson-2.2.2.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

even though the paths are correct.

I tried to look online for how to do it correctly but found irrelevant results only.
I don't accept the situation that I replace the path on his computer with the absolute path on my computer.
I want the project be self dependent only, with all dependencies inside.

I don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I downloaded wrong version of the project.
In the new version, the libraries were already present in `_libraries` subdirectory.

The `.classpath` still contained absolute path to the directory inside the project.
But thus time editing it worked:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="_libraries/gson-2.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="_libraries/ini4j-0.5.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="_libraries/jfreechart-1.0.19/lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

The difference seems to be `exported="true"` from my original example.

This is an incomplete answer because I achieved the goal, I can compile the project without absolute path dependencies but I still don't understand everything.